# sonata remove /index.php from urls

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, redirect, sonata

I am working on a Symfony 2.8 / Sonata project, and I found that all urls a duplicated, one with "/index.php" and the other witout it. 
So this url :

> http://mydomaine.com/index.php/test/test.html

will be redirected to :

> http://mydomaine.com/test/test.html

I tried to use .htaccess to remove it, but it didn't work :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: That's not my work :) , im just trying to hide /index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` to remove `index.php` from URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/.+)$ $1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks but, nothing has changed !

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser?